# "used by" query in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

When viewing, for instance, Tables in [Toad](https://www.quest.com/toad/) a "Used By" facility is available to show you where that Table is made use of (so if a table is referenced in a trigger that will be shown here).

How can I do this outside of Toad in plain old SQL ?

I'm particularly interested in finding where sequences and tables are used .

I've looked at the doco for USER_TABLES, USER_TRIGGERS and USER_SEQUENCES but it's clearly going to need something more than just selecting some columns out of a meta table.

Comment: This isn't my area of expertise so I can't provide a full-blown answer, but try looking at the `user_dependencies`, `all_dependencies`, and `dba_dependencies` views.

Comment: P.S. you know you can see the sql that Toad itself generates when it does things, right? IIRC, it's under: Database > Spool SQL > Spool SQL to Screen.

Comment: @EdGibbs - thanks for your comment. I wasn't aware of those tables - very useful.

Comment: @Boneist - that's just amazing. I wasn't aware of that but I'm going to learn a lot by using it ! Thanks for pointing it out - such a useful feature !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `user_dependencies` or `all_dependencies`

```
SELECT name AS dependant_object,
       type,
       owner object_owner 
FROM all_dependencies
 WHERE referenced_owner = user --Table owned by current user
 AND referenced_type = 'TABLE' AND referenced_name = 'EMPLOYEES';
```

For sequences, you may use `referenced_type = 'SEQUENCE'`

Another option is to scan the source code of packages/functions/procedures and Triggers.

```
SELECT *
  FROM user_source
 WHERE lower(text) like '%employees%';  --table name


SELECT *
  FROM user_source
 WHERE lower(text) like '%emp_seq.nextval%'; --sequence name
```

But, this is not fully reliable as tables of the form `employees_tmp` will also match or `emp_seq . nextval` won't match.